# In MFC, do inactive windows receive PreTranslateMessage events?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have noticed a behaviour and want to confirm that there's no simple way around it. Let's say I have a main CFrameWnd which contains several CViews, often nested several levels deep. Let's say each of them overrides `PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)` (don't shoot me, I inherited this code :P ). The question is: will ALL CViews / CFrameWnd / etc receive a notification to their `PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)`, or is the message consumed by the first `PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)` that processes it?

It appears, based on what I've observed, that only one `PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)` is triggered, but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inactive views will receive PreTranslateMessage calls if the the message that was posted to the Windows message queue was for that view or for a child window of that view.

If the message does not meet the above condition, then the inactive views will not process PreTranslateMessages.

There is PreTranslateMessage and there is the OnCmdMsg routing of menus, toolbars, ribbons, etc.  In that case, the inactive views will not process them by default unless the applications frame window has overridden OnCmdMsg and decides to iterate through all the child views.